# Asking password 2 times while opening Excel files over Internet

Tags: networking, microsoft-excel

The problem is with a Lenovo Iomega IX2 NAS.

When I open Excel files via Internet (IE, Chrome, FF, Win 7, Win 8 ...) on that NAS, it ask me two times to enter a username and a password.

I have to click on cancel 2 times and my Excel file open.

It's happening while I'm already logged with the NAS with a valid NAS account who have full permissions for these Excel files.

It doesn't do that with PDF, MP3 or pictures files.

I also tried to create an account on the NAS that use the same username and password that I'm using on my Windows 7 computer, I gave full permissions, and it still asking me 2 times for a username and password.

Any ideas ?

Thank you.

Comment: 2 things that I think would help (unless someone has run into this before).  1. Is the UN/PW windows from Office, windows, or something else (a screenshot can help)? 2. What happens if you try other office files like a Word Document, Powerpoint, etc.?  You say it happens with multiple Excel Files, but if it happens with multiple office products, it would be useful to know which version of office you are using.

Comment: I have this same problem! Only it occurs when opening Microsoft Office files frm WebDAV Shares. I have to click on cancel thrice, that is the only difference. My speculation is Microsoft Office is unsure/doesn't have the permissions to access your file. Does this occur on other PCs? I am assuming text files/PDFs will open from the same location, right?

Comment: dakre18: Hello, yes it does the same thing with Word and Powerpoint, we use Office 2010 and Office 365 (latest version). Thank you.

Comment: InterLinked: Hello, yes it happened with many computers, PDF and many others files are ok, thank you.